# Ifelse statment across multiple rows

Tags: r, if-statement, boolean, row

Looking to add a column based on the values of two columns, but over more than one row.

**Example Dataset Code:**

```
A = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
B = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2)
C = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1)
data <- data.frame(A,B,C)
```

**Dataset:**

```
   A  B  C
1  1  1  0
2  1  2  0
3  1  3  0
4  2  1  1
5  2  2  0
6  2  3  0
7  3  1  1
8  3  2  1
9  3  3  1
10 4  1  0
11 4  2  1
```

**Ifelse statements:**

What I am trying to achieve is "Create column `D`.If column `C` == 1 in **any row** where column `A` == x, column `D` = 1. Else column `D` == 0"

**Desired Output:**

```
   A  B  C  D
1  1  1  0  0
2  1  2  0  0
3  1  3  0  0
4  2  1  1  1
5  2  2  0  1
6  2  3  0  1
7  3  1  1  1
8  3  2  1  1
9  3  3  1  1
10 4  1  0  1
11 4  2  1  1
```

**What I've done:**

I've thought about it today but can't come up with a logical answer, I've tried looking at the data in long and wide formats but nothings jumped out.

**Note:**
In actual application the number of times x appears in column `C` is not equal (some contain one repeat in the dataset, others contain 20).

Comment: If column C == 1 in any row where column A == x???? , column BBBB = 1. Else column D == 0"

A= x? and D = 1?? should it be A= "some number" and "B" = 1?? Do you even need column B ?

Comment: Column A does not have "x" anywhere.

Comment: @Mandar - I think they mean for each unique value in column `A`. It is *really* unclear though.

Comment: @Mandar, "X" denotes any number

Comment: @thelatemail how would you ask this in a written sense? I was struggling. Want to be as succinct as possible for future questions.

Comment: @T.Williams - "for each unique value in column A" - or "for each group in column A" or something like that I reckon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# just check using any() if any group has a single row with C==1 

library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(D = as.numeric(any(C==1)))

library(data.table)
data[, D:=as.numeric(any(C==1)), by = .(A)]   
#       A     B     C     D
#1      1     1     0     0
#2      1     2     0     0
#3      1     3     0     0
#4      2     1     1     1
#5      2     2     0     1
#6      2     3     0     1
#7      3     1     1     1
#8      3     2     1     1
#9      3     3     1     1
#10     4     1     0     1
#11     4     2     1     1
```

Comment: Excellent. Hadn't found the "any" function before. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Easy with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(data)
x=2
data[,D:=ifelse(!A==x,ifelse(C==1,1,0),0)]
data
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ave` from `base R`

```
data$D <- with(data, as.integer(ave(C==1, A, FUN=any)))
data
#   A B C D
#1  1 1 0 0
#2  1 2 0 0
#3  1 3 0 0
#4  2 1 1 1
#5  2 2 0 1
#6  2 3 0 1
#7  3 1 1 1
#8  3 2 1 1
#9  3 3 1 1
#10 4 1 0 1
#11 4 2 1 1
```